# Is it possible to restrict the output of the help() function for Python packages?

Tags: python

When calling the Python `help()` function on a package I get the following things:

1. The content of the docstring specified in `__init__.py`
2. A list of the package contents containing all modules
3. The version of the package
4. The path of `__init__.py`

As a provider of a customer-oriented software I would like to restrict this output to the relevant information, i.e. not showing those modules that are not meant to be used by the customer.

So, if my package P contains modules A, B and _c, where A and B are meant to be used as a public interface and _c provides just some utility functionality for A and B then I would like to limit the output of `help(P)` to:

```
Help on package P:

Some descriptive text.

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    A
    B

VERSION
    1.0

FILE
    /path/to/P/__init__.py
```

When trying to achieve something similar for modules, I can define my own `__dir__()` function which interestingly is respected by `help(module)`. But trying to apply the same approach to a package (meaning: defining `__dir__()` in `__init__.py`) doesn't achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `help()` comes from the [`pydoc` module](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc).

Looking at [the relevant source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd390ef825c5f2ad86e0966173a6bcaca85a56f2/Lib/pydoc.py#L1239-L1251), the `PACKAGE CONTENTS` section is generated by [`pkgutil.iter_modules()`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.iter_modules), and there's [no hook I can see](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bd390ef825c5f2ad86e0966173a6bcaca85a56f2/Lib/pkgutil.py#L110-L133) that could hide some modules from there (aside from monkey-patching the whole function to hide the modules you want when the stack indicates it's being called from `pydoc`, but I would **strongly** advise against it unless this is an app you're in full control of).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is very unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `__all__` magic variable to provide list of things which should be described after using `help`, let `mymodule.py` be file with content

```
__all__ = ['func1','func2']
def func1():
    '''first function for user'''
    return 1
def func2():
    '''second function for user'''
    return 2
def func3():
    '''function for internal usage'''
    return 3
```

then

```
import mymodule
help(mymodule)
```

gives output

```
Help on module mymodule:

NAME
    mymodule

FUNCTIONS
    func1()
        first function for user

    func2()
        second function for user

DATA
    __all__ = ['func1', 'func2']

FILE
    <path to mymodule.py here>
```

Comment: This does not answer OP's question, since they're talking about package modules, not functions.