Python Module Help DocStrings - Exclucing extra documentation
I have written a simple module (testmodule) which imports some other modules. When I import it and type:
help(testmodule)

I get all of the help from the imported modules as well.
Is there a way of excluding the extra help?
Here is an example of the problem:
#   file: testmodule.py
'''
Test Module etc
'''

import tkinter

#class TestTK(tkinter.Tk):
#   '''Test Class'''
#   pass

When testing the code in a python shell:
import testmodule
help(testmodule)
#   a few lines as expected

When I uncomment the code for the dummy TestTK class:
#   reload module:
import importlib, sys
importlib.reload(sys.modules['testmodule'])

#   try again
help(testmodule)
#   hundreds of addition lines from tkinter


Can you show a [mre]? When I try two simple modules, I import one and open its help, I don't see the help from the other.

Actually I've got the same as @mkrieger1 wrote. That's why I just remind PEP in my answer.

@mkrieger1 I’ve added a minimal example.

@Manngo Here is some explanation how help works: https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pydoc.html#module-pydoc and here ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73049207/is-it-possible-to-restrict-the-output-of-the-help-function-for-python-packages ) is opinion that the problem is organic and unresolvable w/o patching standard module.
